What does the mixture of experiments yield in the following case $qA\cup(1-q)B = ?$?
Let us assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all $M\times N$ matrices such that $M\geq 2$ and $N\geq 2$. A matrix $A\in\mathcal{E}$ is denoted as a matrix where its columns are elements of $[0,1]$ and the elements of each row sum to $1$. Let the rows be the states denoted as $i$ and the columns, denoted as $j$, be the ``signals", that is, a probability where in the state $i$ we will know that the signal $j$ has occurance probability equal to $\alpha_{i,j}\in[0,1]$. Note here that the sum of each column need not to be equal to 1.
If $A\in\mathcal{E}$ and $q\in(0,1)$, then $qA$ denotes the matrix formed by multiplying each entry of $A$ by $q$. If $A, B\in\mathcal{E}$ and $q\in(0,1)$, then $qA\cup(1-q)B$ denotes the matrix formed by appending $(1-q)B$ to the right of $qA$. This mixture yields a well-defined experiment (in the sense of Blackwell Experiments), but the operation of $\cup$ is not commutative.
If we assume that elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are $2\times 2$ matrices, and let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 3/4 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad 
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/3 & 2/3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the rows of each matrix denote the states good $(g)$ and bad $(b)$ and the columns the signals $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively, what does the mixture of experiments yield in the following case
$$qA\cup(1-q)B = ?$$

Well, with your definition $\cup: \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}$ is not well-defined if the dimensions of the matrices have to remain the same. Therefore, we cannot take $\mathcal{E}$ to be the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices. You can however take any convex combination $qA + (1-q)B$, which will lead to another stochastic matrix. (Hence, the set of all $2 \times 2$ stochastic matrices is convex under $+$, just like the original $\mathcal{E}$ under $\cup$). I suspect that taking $+$ instead of $\cup$ is the way to go if the interpretation of the states are the same.

Why is it not well defined? What do I need to change? And why $\mathcal{E}$ can notbe the set of all $2\times 2$ smatrices? Thank you in advance

Because it does not map two $2\times2$ matrices onto a $2\times2$ matrix. I don't know what you could change, because I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

@MrTheOwl in page $7$ (or $2087$) of this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.3982/ECTA16729 they define this operation $qA\cup(1-q)B$. Should I try to give more notation in my question?
